# Data generation method of DeepSort + Yolov5 algorithm

Tags: image, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

First of all, I am practicing based on
'https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch'.

Question 1

Is the created txt file a file to which both yolo algorithm and deepsort algorithm are applied?

Question 2

I trained the detector yolo to apply it on custom data.
Does deepsort also need to train custom data afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

Yolov5 performs object detection. The generated bounding boxes are passed to Deep Sort which tracks the objects. Tracking is done by an association based on two things:

1. Mahalanobis distance between predicted Kalman states and newly arrived measurements
2. Appearance descriptor

In combination, both metrics complement each other by serving different aspects of the assignment problem. The Mahalonobis distance is suitable when the motion uncertainty is low, but when there is occlusion and/or unaccounted frame skipping the Mahalanobis distance is rather useless. Therefore, the idea is to use a visual metric to complement the motion metric. In order to do this an appearance descriptor is calculated for each bounding box detection and are compared to a "gallery" of appearance descriptors, this is particularly useful to recover identities after long-term occlusions or rapid displacements.

So, yes. Both Yolo and DeepSort are used to generate the txt file.

**Question 2.**

In the original [Deep Sort paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07402.pdf) it is stated that the appearance descriptors are generated by a CNN trained on MARS as stated. [Some implementations](https://github.com/ZQPei/deep_sort_pytorch#training-the-re-id-model) of Deep Sort also uses the Market1501 dataset for this purpose. Both of them only contains persons. They choose these datasets because they focus on the MOT challenge dataset which only contains persons.

So, ideally you would train your own appearance descriptor on the class you want to track.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the YOLOv5 model performs object detection, and the Deepsort model associates tracks to detections by looking at the feature maps. They are very different models and thus have to be trained separately. I have not been able to train the deep sort tracker for my custom data yet. I will update this answer when I am able to finish training.

Answer (score 0):

**Question-1** - the txt file will have classes detected and their coordinates mentioned and yes deepsort and yolo are applied on both

**Question-2** - No,you d'nt need to train yolo and deepsort separately,it will be done in a single step